# Yii Query optimization MySQL

Tags: mysql, model, yii

I am not very good with DB queries. And with Yii it's more complicated, since I am not very used to it.
I need to optimize a simple query

```
   $userCalendar = UserCalendar::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>$user->id));
   $unplannedEvents = CalendarEvent::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('calendar_id'=> $userCalendar->calendar_id,'planned'=>0));
```

CalendarEvent table, i.e the second table from which I need records does not have an user_id but a calendar_id from which I could get user_id from UserCalendar, i.e. the first table hence I created a UserCalendar object which is not a very good way as far as I understand.
Q1. What could I do to make it into one.
Q2. Yii does this all internally but I want to know what query it built to try it seperately in MySQL(phpMyAdmin), is there a way to do that? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Q1: You need to have the relation between UserCalendar and CalendarEvent defined in both of your active record models (in the method "relations").

Based on your comments, it seems like you have the Calendar model that has CalendarEvent models and UserCalendar models.
Lets assume your relations in Calendar are:

```
relations() {
    return array( 
      'userCalendar' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserCalendar', 'calendar_id'),
      'calendarEvent' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CalendarEvent', 'calendar_id'),
}
```

In CalendarEvent:

```
relations() { 
    return array( 'calendar' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Calendar', 'calendar_id'), );
}
```

And in UserCalendar:

```
relations() { 
        return array( 'calendar' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Calendar', 'calendar_id'), );
    }
```

So to make the link between `UserCalendar` and `CalendarEvent` you'll need to use Calendar

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array(
   "calendarEvent"=>array('condition'=>'planned = 0'),
   "userCalendar"=>array('condition'=> 'user_id =' . $user->id),
);
$calendar = Calendar::model()->find($criteria);
```

and `$calendar->calendarEvent` will return an array of calendarEvent belonging to the user

Q2: you can enable web logging so all the db request (and others stuffs) will appear at the end of your page:
[Logging in Yii (see CWebLogging)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging)

In your application configuration put

```
'components'=>array(
        ......
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',

                ),
           ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Both Active REcord classes have the desired relations.In CalendarEvent public function relations()
 {
  return array(
   'calendar' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Calendar', 'calendar_id'),
  );
 } and in UserCalendar  public function relations()
 {
  return array(
   'calendar' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Calendar', 'calendar_id'),
   'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
  );
 } Your query does not seem to work. And for logging, I can't see where is the message logged.

Comment: I have 'log'=>array(
   'class'=>'CLogRouter',
   'routes'=>array(
    array(
     'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
     'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
    ), in my main.php but there is no CFileLogRoute in my webapp directory. Kindly elaborate your answer. Thanks.

Comment: For the log route i think the log file is created in the folder "runtime" (for example in my app I have the file application.log) You can display the logs on the webpage with: 
array('class' => 'CWebLogRoute',),

Comment: For the relations, watching what you described in your comment it seems like you have 3 tables: UserCalendar, Calendar and CalendarEvent, is that right? If not it means your relation's definitions are wrong. Tell me and I'll help you to get the rights ones

Comment: 1. You're right there is a file in runtime folder, it does display the query, isn't the query to complex to understand? :( 2. The relations aren't wrong I do have a Calendar table. It's like every user has a calendar. :) I'll be glad if you could help. :)

Comment: My current query looks like this,       $userCalendar = UserCalendar::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id'=>$user->id));
    $unplannedEvents = CalendarEvent::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('calendar_id'=> $userCalendar->calendar_id,
     'planned'=>0),
        'condition'=>array( 'start_time'=> 'between :start AND :end'),
        'params'=>array(':start'=>$date, ':end' => $date . ' 23:59:59'));

Comment: It doesn't give any records. This is working,   $unplannedEvents = CalendarEvent::model()->findAllBySql(
    'SELECT * FROM `calendar_event` WHERE calendar_id =:calendar_id and planned = 0 and event_start between :start AND :end',
      array(':calendar_id'=>$userCalendar->id, ':start'=>$date, ':end' => $date . ' 23:59:59'));